# Node.js - Handle net connection in a forked process

Tags: node.js

The purpose is to run every authorized user in a separate process.

`cluster` module is great but i need to assign forked process to specific user by cookies.

So the idea is to fork a process for every authorized user, accept connections in the master process and pass them to corresponding forked process.

`index.js` - master process:

```js
const net = require("net");
const child_process = require("child_process");


const worker = child_process.fork("worker.js")
const server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true })

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
  worker.send("socket", socket)
})

server.listen(8080)
```

`worker.js`

```js
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // app logic
})

process.on("message", function(msg, socket) {
  server.listen(socket)
})
```

So far so good, master process accepting connections and passing them to child process.

Child process receiving the socket and... here is the question: how to make `http` server handle received socket.

`server.listen(socket)` is throwing

```
NET 400498: _read
NET 400522: onconnection
NET 400530: _read
NET 400530: Socket._handle.readStart
NET 400530: setupListenHandle null -1 -1 0 undefined
NET 400530: setupListenHandle: have a handle already
Error: listen EINVAL: invalid argument
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1320:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1368:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1423:5)
    at process.<anonymous> (./worker.js:29:10)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:910:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  code: 'EINVAL',
  errno: -22,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: null,
  port: -1
}
```

Error generated by this line: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.17.4/lib/net.js#L1317

My setup

```
➜ uname -a
Linux sleewoo 5.4.150-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 30 16:13:54 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
➜ node -v
v14.17.4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is absolutely legit - two servers can not listen on same port.

I misunderstood the statement about `server.listen(handle[, backlog][, callback])` here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/net.html#net_server_listen_handle_backlog_callback

> The handle object can be either a server, a socket (anything with an underlying _handle member), or an object with an fd member that is a valid file descriptor.

The correct way: allow server listen on a random port and notify the server about new connections.

`index.js` - master process:

```js
server.on("connection", function(connection) {
  worker.send("connection", connection)
})
```

`worker.js`

```js
process.on("message", function(msg, val) {
  if (msg === "connection") {
    server.emit("connection", val)
  }
})

server.listen(0, "localhost")
```